# Check if one item in a listing has specific class - get as var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, var

I have a listing which is dynamicly generated by a php script, it looks like that:

```
<li id="01" class="default">Element</li>
<li id="02" class="default">Element</li>
<li id="03" class="default">Element</li>
<li id="04" class="default">Element</li>
<li id="05" class="default active">Element</li>
<li id="06" class="default">Element</li>
```

Now I need a jQuery script which saves me the ID of the element which has the class ACTIVE an variable.

How I am gonna do this the proper way?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.attr()`:

```
$('li.active').attr('id');
```

**[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2sXQ/)**

Comment: So it looks like thi in my code:
`var asdf = $("li.active").attr("id");`
and then I do this:
`asdf.removeClass("active");`
and this error shows up:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object 17 has no method 'removeClass' `

Comment: `$("#" + asdf).removeClass("active")` to be precise. The hashtag is not part of the ID attribute.

Answer (score 1):

> Use attr() in jquery.Get the value of an attribute for the first
>   element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes
>   for every matched element.

```
 $(".active").attr("id");
```